# How to tell if I'm pseudoreplicating in a mixed model by taking slices of the same measurement

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-regression, pseudorepliction

Here is my data setup.  The dependent variable is mean resultant length (MRL), i.e., in context, the degree to which a firing unit is firing in phase with a particular frequency of the local field potential in the brain.  The variables of interest are group, neuron type, and period type.  Other variables are animal, unit (neuron), period, and frequency bin.  The analysis is happening within grosser frequency bins (for example, 4-12 Hz), but I also have finer grained frequency bins, because I got phase data from the local field potential by sampling within the range, so I have a different answer for different frequencies between 4 and 12.

Here is what I'd like to do:

```
mrl ~ group * neuron_type * period_type + period + frequency_bin + (1|animal)
```

Or

```
mrl ~ group * neuron_type * period_type + frequency_bin + (1|animal/unit)
```

My reasoning here is that even though period and frequency bin aren't variables of interest it's reasonable to call either of them fixed effects.  I'm not trying to generalize to the whole population of periods or frequency bins and in each case they're a series of numbers that were the same for every animal.  I'm just paranoid that one or both of these models is introducing pseudoreplication by creating the illusion that a data point that differs from another only by frequency bin was a separate observation, when it's actually a mathematical slice of an observation.  Why don't you average over frequency bin, you ask? Because then I just don't get results, which is part of what makes me wonder whether the above models aren't legitimate in some way.